# AC Door bell rings continuosly

Tags: ac

I have a new wired door bell which has two source of power i.e. from AA batteries and AC grid. On connecting the bell to bell switch, the bell rings continuosly even though the switch is not pressed. This was not the case with my old bell which gets power from AC grid alone. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Stuck relay inside it?

Answer (score 1):

1-1st of all check all connections, make aure they are right in place,
2-check model of door bell and manual,
3-in many Chinese versions of door bells, the switch is heavily pressed while shipping, which make it faulty switch, if you have multimeter, just check on continuity mode the two probe of switches, if it is shorted, then you have to request new one,